# Use gdb within Emacs: always show the source code

Tags: c++, c, emacs

I'm a Vim user and don't know much about Emacs. I'm interested with Emacs because I find that debugging within Emacs is more pleasant. For example, it provides syntax highlighting and I can set breakpoints with the mouse.

Everything works well except when `printf` is encountered.

Simple code for illustration:

```
1 #include <stdio.h>
2 
3 int main()
4 {
5     int a = 1;
6     printf("%d\n", a);
7     int b = 2;
8     return 0;
9 }
```

*emacs main.c

left click on the bottom half

M-x gdb[return][return]

(gdb) b 6

(gdb) r*

By now, the **source codes** are showed in the upper half, and **gdb prompt** in the bottom half. This is exactly what I want.

*(gdb) n*

Now the source codes disappear, and the upper half is used to show stdout instead. This is really inconvenient. I'd like the stdout to show in the gdb buffer, and the sources stay in the upper buffer, just as the `gdb -tui` mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of manually setting up your splits each time, try [telling GDB which windows you want available](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/GDB-User-Interface-Layout.html#GDB-User-Interface-Layout).

For example:

```lisp
;; Show main source buffer when using GDB
(setq gdb-show-main t)
```

Now you can simply use `M-x gdb` to start GDB, and it should keep your source code buffer displayed in a split window.

Incidentally, Emacs' GDB interface supports a number of other windows that you may want to enable:

> If `gdb-many-windows` is non-`nil`, then `M-x gdb` displays the
>   following frame layout:
>
> ```lisp
> +--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
> |   GUD interaction buffer       |   Locals/Registers buffer      |
> |--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
> |   Primary Source buffer        |   I/O buffer for debugged pgm  |
> |--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
> |   Stack buffer                 |   Breakpoints/Threads buffer   |
> +--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
> ```
>
> If you ever change the window layout, you can restore the "many
>   windows" layout by typing `M-x gdb-restore-windows`.  To toggle between
>   the many windows layout and a simple layout with just the GUD
>   interaction buffer and a source file, type `M-x gdb-many-windows`.
>
> You may also specify additional GDB-related buffers to display,
>   either in the same frame or a different one.  Select the buffers you
>   want by typing `M-x gdb-display-BUFFERTYPE-buffer` or `M-x gdb-frame-BUFFERTYPE-buffer`, where BUFFERTYPE is the relevant buffer
>   type, such as `breakpoints`.  You can do the same with the menu bar,
>   with the `GDB-Windows` and `GDB-Frames` sub-menus of the `GUD` menu.
>
> When you finish debugging, kill the GUD interaction buffer with `C-x k`,
>   which will also kill all the buffers associated with the session.
>   However you need not do this if, after editing and re-compiling your
>   source code within Emacs, you wish to continue debugging.  When you
>   restart execution, GDB automatically finds the new executable.  Keeping
>   the GUD interaction buffer has the advantage of keeping the shell
>   history as well as GDB's breakpoints.  You do need to check that the
>   breakpoints in recently edited source files are still in the right
>   places.

Comment: Accept for "gdb-many-windows". I add `(setq gdb-many-windows t)` to my .emacs file. ps:`(setq gdb-show-main t)` doesn't solve the printf problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

You might also like to try `M-x gud-gdb`.  It's a much more bare-bones UI, but I personally prefer it.

Comment: This solves my problem at the cost of introducing another problem: the GUI won't show the breakpoints and I can't add breakpoints via the mouse.